# Simple python search through log files script is sorted but completes out of order after 30 files

Tags: python, file, sorting, search

I have a simple python script that searches through files in a directory for a search term and its sorted by os.path.getctime (get creation time). When I print the list of file names directly it's printing them in order of latest to oldest correctly. But when I try to execute this code, past 30 or so files it does not start with the latest. If I ony search the first 30 or so files it works as expected. Could someone tell me if this is a python thing or if there is something wrong with my code? What am I doing wrong? See code below.

```
import os

os.chdir('/home/user/logs/')
mystr = input('search string: ')


files = sorted(os.listdir('.'),key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)

def search(start, stop):
    for file in files[start:stop]:
        print(file)
        with open(file, 'r') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                if mystr in line:
                    print(line)


search(0,31) #works
search(0,400) #searches out of order or starts at weird order number.
```

Comment: Inside your search method, just before the loop, print out the files variable to see what it contains

Comment: yeah when i do that it prints out the file names all correctly in order

Comment: Can you just try this `files[:30] ` and then  `files[:400] `and see if you get the correct output. Also in this case I will much prefer this `subprocess.Popen("ls - lrt", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, instead of using sorted function with os.path.getctime as key as I am not sure how the sorting would work for a time field.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, it looks like the problem I was having was the way it was displayed in my terminal (I use linux). When I write the output to a file everything looks correct.